# How to pass fagment manager from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have one class:

```
class a extend fragment
{
    adt a=new adp(fragmentmanager());
    /* here is the error -> fragmentmanager undefined */ 
}
```

And another class which accept the FragmentManager:

```
class adt extend fragmentpageadapter
{
    public adt (FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Please any one help me to find out how I can send FragmentManager object within Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

```
getFragmentManager()
```

or

```
getActivity().getSupportedFragmentManager()
```

or

```
getActivity().getFragementManager()
```

In the recent version of support libs where fragment can be a child of another fragment you can also try with

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```

Comment: what error are you getting? compile time or runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

Within a Fragment, I use

```
getActivity().getFragementManager()
```

To get a FragmentManager object.